# If/Else condition is changing the value of variable (SparkAR)

Tags: javascript, spark-ar-studio

**I'm facing this weird problem within SparkAR.**

I was trying to pull data from the patch editor and passing it to a if/else but it wasn't working. I removed everything to see where the problem is and it seems like this code:

```
function compareAlpha(){
    var alpha = 0;
    if (alpha = 1){
      Diagnostics.log('alpha is 1')
    } else {
      Diagnostics.log('alpha is not 1')
    }
  };
  compareAlpha();
```

Shows up as "alpha is 1" which to me sounds crazy. I'm declaring alpha as 0 then the if condition is changing it to 1??

Sorry if it's a very stupid question, I'm just starting coding and the documentation on spark website isn't that easy to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function compareAlpha(){
    var alpha = 0;
    if (alpha === 1){
      Diagnostics.log('alpha is 1')
    } else {
      Diagnostics.log('alpha is not 1')
    }
  };
  compareAlpha();
```

pleasse use == or === to check condition otherwise it will not work. there is mutiple use of = sign if you use 1 time = its mean you are intilize a value in variale and if you use 2 o 3 = then its mean you are comparing right hand side to left hand side

Comment: Ahh!! I was so stressed on finding what wasn't working that I totally forgot about that! Sorry! Can I also ask you how to "listen" to a variable? Right now the code get executed only at the start.. then the variable changes but nothing happens.

Comment: i think there is an issue in your **diagnostic**.. so please first console like **function compareAlpha(){
    var alpha = 0;
    if (alpha === 1){
      console.log('alpha is 1')
    } else {
      console.log('alpha is not 1')
    }
  };
  compareAlpha();**

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "pull" any data from the patch editor.

You need to explicitly pass the data from the patch editor to the script.

The simplest example:

1. Create new blank project
2. Add script and in its settings create "To script" Number variable
   [See Pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILTA5.png)

Now you can in the script access the variable "alpha" through the module "Patches"

3. Add this code to the script

```
const Patches = require('Patches');
const Diagnostics = require('Diagnostics');

// monitor() and subscribe() methods allows you yo "listen" variable changes in patch editor
Patches.outputs.getScalar('alpha').then(function(alphaSignal){
    alphaSignal.monitor().subscribe(function(alphaVal){
        if(alphaVal.newValue == 1)
        {
            Diagnostics.log('alpha is 1');
        }
        else
        {
            Diagnostics.log('alpha is not 1');
        }
    });
});
```

4. Everything already works, let's do some simple check and make sure that the necessary messages are displayed in the console. For example, a set of patches that changes the alpha value back and forth. [See Pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbTpM.png)

Comment: Thank you Igor! However the issue I was having wasn't about pulling data. I was trying to pull data and it didn't work, so I removed everything and left the if/else condition alone and realised that was broken. When @arslan told me about the '==' operator then I fixed the if/else and my code started working again. Thank you anyway for the screenshot and code, I'm sure many will find it useful!!

Comment: I'm also gonna add that for Boolean values you can use .onOn or .onOff to monitor only when the variable becomes true or false instead of every change. So: 
`alphaSignal.onOn({fireOnInitialValue: false})` 
will only execute the code when alpha becomes true.